# How do I capitalize input?

Tags: python

The following code, is the one I want it to be capitalized. Meaning once the user inputs their answer to the licence plate, I want it to be outputted in capitals:

```
ask2 = ""
    plate = ""
    if int(ask) == 1:
        stop = False
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("========================================================================")
        while not stop:
            ask2 = input("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): ").lower()
            valid = re.compile("[a-z][a-z]\d\d[a-z][a-z][a-z]\Z")
                                # b will start and end the program, meaning no more than 3-4 letters will be used.
            # The code which tells the user to enter the right format (keeps looping)
            # User can exit the loop by typing 'exit'
            # This is the default exit_message
            exit_message = "Verification Failed!"
            while (not valid.match(ask2)) and (ask2 != 'exit'):
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print("========================================================================\n", exit_message,
                      sep="")
                print("You can exit the validation by typing 'exit'.")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print("========================================================================")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                ask2 = input("Or stick to the rules, and enter it in such form (XX00XXX): ").lower()
                if ask2 == 'exit':
                    exit_message = "Verification Stopped!"
                    stop = True
                    break
```

I already have constructed a code to make it capitalized, this is it; however I have no idea where to put it:

```
var = input("no caps: ")
def isvalid(s):
    for i in s:
        if i in "ABC...XYZ":
            return False
    return True

while not isvalid(var):
def isvalid(s):
    for i in s:
        if i in "ABC...XYZ":
            return False
    return True
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: do you mean `"hello world".capitalize()` or `"hello world".upper()` ?

Comment: In a way yes; however, I am trying to make sure the inputted answer comes out as capital letters. Keep in mind the user is inputting the answer.

Comment: `"hello world".isupper()` ? `while not var.isupper()` ?

Comment: Problem is, I am not capitalizing one word.
Rather a whole input that the user inputs, I've no idea what it will turn out to be.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [`upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) method.

```
>>> "hello".upper()
'HELLO'
```

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately. The code I've provided will work on the other hand, I simply want to know where I place it. I am a little confused by all the loops.